# Replace application.vlookup with vlookup(R1C1..)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the application.worksheetfunction to do a vlookup as follows:

```
For i = 4 to LastRow
    Cells(i, 35) = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(Cells(i, 12), Sheets("Risk Explorer greeks").Range("A1:C50000"), 3, 0), Cells(i, 15))
Next i
```

As this takes a long time I've tried to replace it by using the following code:

```
Range("AI:AI" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-21],'Risk Explorer greeks'!R2C1:R50000C3, 3, False),"Range("O4:O" & LastRow)"
```

However it's giving me an error, I believe because of the last piece of code that comes in to play when the error occurs. In my first bit of code, if the vlookup failed in cell 50, then the iferror would lookup a value in row 15 column 50 and give that back. This is what I'm trying to achieve by the second bit of code I'm using, but it doesnt seem to work. can anyone help me out pls?

I've been playing around with this for a while but can't seem to resolve!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a start row for your Range object, and you want the value in column 15 of the current row in the formula so:

```
Range("AI4:AI" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-21],'Risk Explorer greeks'!R2C1:R50000C3, 3, False),RC15)"
```